# Нужно через библиотеку Kivy на Python присвоить окну цветовую схему Windows

Tags: python, kivy, background

Как можно установить цвета Windows внутри разрабатываемого через Kivy окна? Через RGB бэкграунд не вариант, это уже кастыль получится, при том не рабочий, так как на другом компьютере с другой цветовой схемой это не прокатит. Искал по справочнику Kivy, но не нашёл ничего похожего на передачу цвета от ОС.
И возможно ли сделать окно прозрачным с помощью Kivy?
Уточнение: Мне нужно чтобы окно моей программы принимало тему виндовс вместо чёрного полотна. Примерно как в TKinter, если не трогать бэкграунд. В Kivy просто оно чёрное. Я конечно могу поменять на другой цвет, но мне нужно чтобы именно значение цвета бралось из темы винды, а не из библиотеки. То есть цвет обычных окон виндовс.

Comment: Не вводите людей в заблуждение! Kivy/KivyMD - это как раз для всего!

Comment: В tkinter'е я упёрся в потолок. Мне нужно было сделать фреймы которые перемещались бы по окну программы при зажатой ЛКМ. + заголовок окна опять же нельзя убрать.

Comment: У каждого виджета есть `canvas`. Вы можете раскрасить свое окно во все цвета радуги. Но я согласен - уточните вопрос!

Comment: Забудьте о Tkinter - это рудимент!

Comment: Дописал уточнение